# Premission denied when trying to save file to sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Im trying to save a textfile to the sd card but i am getting the Eacess (permission deined) error. My code looks as following:

```
      try {
            File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myfile");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(text.getText());
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I have already allowed the `

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
```

in the android manifest

Ive been looking at some other posts relating this issues but nothing solved it.

What am i missing?

**Update my manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.files"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.files.FilesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: First, post your whole manifest, so we can confirm that your `<uses-permission>` is in the proper place. Second, never use concatenation to create a  `File` object -- use the proper `File` constructor that takes a directory `File` and the filename `String`. Third, do not use `getBaseContext()` -- use `this`. Fourth, don't use `Toast` for sole debugging output -- use `Log.e()` so you can see the full stack trace and confirm precisely what line the problem occurs on.

Comment: @CommonsWare added the manifest file to the question

Comment: Well, the `<uses-permission>` seems to be in the right place, which occasionally trips up developers. Next, it would be useful if you would post the entire stack trace and indicate which line in your source code is generating the exception. Also, if you are running this on an emulator, make sure you gave the emulator some external storage (e.g., fill in `32` for the SD card size).

Comment: Oh yeah sorry -.- i forgot to add size to sd card please post it as a reponse so i can accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save files to external storage, it helps to have external storage. :-)

Unfortunately, the AVD Manager defaults to having no external storage (even though I have suggested that they change this). So, if you are using an emulator, double-check to make sure that you have filled in a value for the "SD Card" size.

I usually allocate something small, like 32MB -- enough that you can work with external storage, not so much that it chews up a bunch of your hard drive or slows down the initial AVD launch. Of course, if you are planning on testing something that needs a lot more external storage than that, pick a value that suits.